# Authenticating error while signing in to EMM agent App

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-iot

I have successfully got the credentials on my mail id for enrolling my device through WSO2 EMM. But when i am signing in using the mail credentials its giving an error which `"Enrollment failed -Please contact administrator "`

The logs were:

```
Chrome/44.0.2403.133 Mobile Safari/537.36"
172.17.29.121 - - [16/Jun/2016:12:34:53 +0530] "GET /emm-web-agent/public/asset-download-agent-android/asset/android-agent.apk HTTP/1.1" 200 2896941 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1)"
172.17.29.121 - - [16/Jun/2016:12:35:32 +0530] "GET /emm-web-agent/public/asset-download-agent-android/asset/android-agent.apk HTTP/1.1" 200 590411 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1)" 
172.17.29.121 - - [16/Jun/2016:12:40:13 +0530] "GET /emm-web-agent/public/asset-download-agent-android/asset/android-agent.apk HTTP/1.1" 200 590411 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1) 
172.17.29.121 - - [16/Jun/2016:12:42:45 +0530] "POST /dynamic-client-web/register HTTP/1.1" 201 148 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ), Android"
172.17.29.121 - - [16/Jun/2016:12:42:45 +0530] "POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1" 200 160 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)"
172.17.29.121 - - [16/Jun/2016:12:42:45 +0530] "GET /mdm-android-agent/device/license HTTP/1.1" 401 23 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ), Android"
```

Comment: What is the EMM version you are using? Can you please verify you have given appropriate permission (login permission) to the user

Comment: I am using EMM (2.0.1) and i have given the user appropriate permissions for accessing it.

Comment: Can you check whether you can log into EMM console using the credentials in the mail. I have tried this using EMM 201 pack, and I was able to reproduce the issue when the user do not have enough permissions. (To enroll a device use should minimum have login and enrollment permission. These permissions are available at the bottom of the permission tree)

Comment: Were you able to login to EMM console with user credentials? Also did you check whether you have added 'enroll' permission as well?

Comment: yes i checked, but i was not able to sign in

Comment: Could you try to create another user and add the default admin role to the user through the EMM console. (This is to verify whether the issue is related to user permissions). Then try to login to EMM console using the user credentials in the registration mail.

Answer (score 1):

According to the conversation the problem is with the permission you have provided to the given user role.
You can use an existing role with device management permission as sashika has suggested.
There is a login permission as the very last permission entry in the permission management UI, please include that permission to the related role in order to overcome the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add permissions to the role - specifically the "enroll" role.